# C File Programming - Replace a text in a file using POSIX Calls

Tags: c

Is there a way to replace any keyword in a text file using POSIX calls, without re creating the file..
If yes Please tell me how to do it..

Thanks in advance..

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If the text and the replacement are the same size then you can open it with mode `r+`, seek, and then write. If their sizes are different then there is no way to replace without recreating.